# Using SSI (Server Side Includes)

Tags: html, ssi

I'm trying to learn how to do Server Side Includes because I need them for a project of mine.  Now, can I use SSI locally?  My site is 100% HTML, Javascript, and CSS, so there is no server running my stuff.  I'm just editing the files in notepad.  What can I do to allow me to work on SSI before I upload it to the server that I plan on sending it to.

Comment: It depends on which type of server and which server-side language is supported.

Comment: I know the server I plan on uploading it to supports it, but I need a way to visualize it locally on my own computer.  Is this possible?  Do I need to download a custom server?

Comment: You need to download a server. It doesn't need to be custom. Off-the-shelf is fine.

Comment: Once again, do you want to use IIS or Apache?

Comment: Oh umm... let me go do some research on the subject real quick ;)

Comment: I haven't heard of anyone using SSI for years. It was briefly popular in the '90s before PHP went mainstream, but since then it's virtually sunk without trace. I would suggest using PHP instead. But either way, the answer is yes, you're going to need to install a web server application on your local PC. See my answer. But don't worry; it's really not that difficult (and as I say, if you're going to be a web developer, it's something you really need to know about anyway)

Comment: I see lots of SSI. There's a fair amount at the [BBC](http://bbc.co.uk). It is a simple, reliable, lightweight technology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What can I do to allow me to work on SSI before I upload it to the server...?

If you're not running a server, then you can't use server-side includes. The clue is in the name. So if you're testing the page locally without a server, then your SSIs won't work.

The only way you're going to be able to do this is to install a web server on your local PC.

Fortunately this is fairly easy. The two major web servers are Apache and IIS. Apache is free; you can download it and install it for free. IIS is a commercial product (by Microsoft), but there is a cut-down version you can install for free. Pick whichever one is best for you (ie the one which matches your actual web server), and you should be able to get your SSI code working. You'll probably need to do some config to set it up, but as a web developer that's a good thing to know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a server locally to make ssi work. You can install just apache, or use XAMPP (lite) to also get PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Server Side Includes (SSI) are an optional feature of the web servers helping the developers to include HTML file content from a base file into multiple other HTML files with a single line of code. We need this if we are creating a simple, elegant and fast pure HTML site, without active server computing, just invoking content delivery capabilities of the server.

There are 3 major steps required to get SSI running on IIS 7 and later:

- Configure IIS roles,
- Extend IIS handlers,
- Invoke a SSI call in you HTML code.

[HERE](http://www.milevis.com/Tips/Details/51) is a more detailed explanation.